# Unable to select _ts from Cosmos db in databricks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-cosmosdb, azure-databricks

unable to select _ts from cosmos db from python script written in databricks.

```
read_config = {
    "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint": url,
    "spark.cosmos.accountKey": key,
    "spark.cosmos.database": database,
    "spark.cosmos.container": container,
    "spark.cosmos.read.customQuery" : "select * from c "
}

rsltdf = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**read_config).load()
display(rsltdf)
```

This select is selecting fields apart from auto generated fields like _ts, _etag. _rid..

Databricks runtime version - 7.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)

libraries - com.azure.cosmos.spark:azure-cosmos-spark_3-3_2-12:4.18.1, azure-cosmos, pyDocumentDB

Comment: Try running a custom query for your read, where you explicitly ask for `_ts` and see if that helps you get the data you need.

Comment: I tried _ts in the select statement, but no luck

Comment: Please edit your question to show *how* you tried to retrieve `_ts` - it's still not anywhere in your question, nor are there any results shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David mentioned you need to query `_ts` explicitly.

Make sure to give alias for it.

```
select c.name ,c._ts as ts, c._etag as etag from c
```

`Output:`

[image]

Comment: This is why it's important for the OP to show their work, to clarify what they're trying. Also FYI [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Ok sure i will add output in table format.

Comment: After adding alias for _ts is working now. Thank you @JayashankarGS